# Normalization and Unique Ids

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, normalization

I have a table titled `videos`. In it there are three columns: `media_id`, `project_id`, and `video_url`. My questions is, is it necessary for me to have `media_id`? I'm not using it in any other tables. I would expect there to be multiple `project_id`s with the same number but different `video_url`s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having or not having surrogate ID's for something has nothing to do with normalization.

(copyright catcall)

Having or not having surrogate ID's for something depends on whether or not you have a useful use for it.  You already gave the answer to that yourself.  And it depends on whether or not there is a significant likelihood that, even if there is no actual use for it right now, such a use might quickly emerge in a nearby future.

Comment: I'll happily upvote *any* answer that mentions me. Ha, ha, ha.

Answer (score 1):

You could use project_id and video_url as a function dependency key in your model but at a physical level I would not like to use a URL as part of a key.

By this I mean I prefer an ID or number to avoid typing in long string each time the key is referenced in different tables.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider it necessary. This is purely based on the fact that the media entry is unique and there could be multiple media entries for any one project. This keeps a unique id for the row, a proper project relationship and the valuable URL data for the media resource.

Comment: You can add a meaningless, surrogate key ID number to every table that doesn't have one, and, by definition, it will be unique. That alone doesn't make it a good idea. Identifying *rows* isn't important; identifying the real-world things the row represents is  important.